# Unable to start service in window 10 by using NSSM

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-services, window, windows-10

I have create a small script file to test.

This my **script.bat** file.

```
sc create myService binpath= C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.bat start= auto
```

This is my **test.bat** file.

```
echo "Welcome to Wizard"
```

**Problem Statement**

I am unable to start the service from **control panel** Service section.

I get following error.

**[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:
    The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.**

That is why I am using nssm.

NOW what happening is that when I run following command on powershell

**.\nssm install myService**, I dialogue box appears. I give it the path of my script file and click on install service.

After successfull installation of service. I go to control panel -> Service -> click on start against **myService** but it get paused and following dialog box appears

[image]

1. How can I fix this?
2. Is there anyother way to do it without doing manual steps and not using third party tool.
3. I am doing all this on window 10. Do I need any server to perform this task?

NOTE: I cannot use Always up or window scheduler in my case.

Comment: Could be because your script exits immediately.  What did you configure for the "action on exit"?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I have not configure anything yet I am just trying to create a basic file as I am new in batch scripting but in future I wanna run logstash as a background service.

Comment: Did you see the comment about Windows 10 users needing to use a specific build?: https://nssm.cc/download -- "Windows 10 Creators Update

2017-04-26: Users of Windows 10 Creators Update should use prelease build 2.2.4-101 to avoid an issue with services failing to start. If for some reason you cannot use that build you can also set AppNoConsole=1 in the registry, noting that applications which expect a console window may behave unexpectedly."

Comment: @andyb In my script I  will be taking some input from user by using cmd or powershell then I will create some directories and extract logstash setup and run it as a  service. I cannot changes things in registry or use any third party that is the limitation. Do you have any other solution? Or if I write a complete service. Will I still face this issue?

Comment: I don't know. I've never used NSSM, but noticed the advisory. Might be worth trying the alternate build they specify.

Comment: By build you mean that I uninstall the updates till you specified?

Comment: I mean try using the pre-release version 2.2.4-101, as they suggest. It looks like NSSM is a stand-alone executable, so you should be able to just replace the copy that you've been using with the pre-release version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152017/discussion-between-andyb-and-miki-jay).

Comment: This is not a programming issue and thus doesn't belong on SO. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is a more appropriate place for questions like this.

Comment: I doubt the binary path will work with a text file (.bat files are text, not binary, and need to be executed by cmd.exe).

Comment: OP is using NSSM, @Bill_Stewart, so service entry will be pointing to an executable. NSSM doco does state that it can execute scripts, without needing to specify CMD.EXE. Indeed, I tried it myself and it does work.

Comment: Ok, so presuming that's not broken in some way, it _should_ work...but in any case this is off-topic for SO...

Comment: @MikiJay, if your script is literally just `echo Hello World`, then it will terminate almost instantly. NSSM default behaviour is to attempt re-start. If it sees that the service keeps terminating, it goes into a paused state. Try adding a `pause` command on the last line of the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NSSM behaviour is caused by the script terminating almost instantly. Try the following script:

`echo Hello World
pause`

This should allow the service to start, but you will not necessarily see a console window. Even if you tick 'allow service to interact with desktop', it will not be your desktop that it interacts with!

Windows implements 'session zero isolation' as a security feature, and this essentially prevents services interacting with end user desktops.

In terms of a solution, it's possible to write Windows 'service' applications fairly simply using Visual Studio. It's outside my area of expertise, but based on the Windows applications I'm familiar with, you would generally have a user-mode application running to provide desktop interaction. The user-mode application can interact with services hosted by the service application.

Comment: I have added the pause statement but same behaviour :( I have also tried to run exe file instead of bat but issue is still same. For developing services in VS in not an option right now. I will see the links that you gave me then get back to you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Verify the batch file behaves as expected by launching it from Windows explorer (double-click on it). You should see a console window, with the message displayed, followed by a prompt to press a key. Press a key and the console window will close.

Comment: The batch file in which I have added an echo is opening and closes when I press a key but the file in which I am creating a service is not opening. (Script.bat) sc create myService binpath= C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.bat start= auto

Comment: I am using window 10. Do I need a server to create this service?

Comment: NSSM will work on Win 10. I started a batch file as a service win NSSM on my Win10 laptop yesterday. Depending on how your laptop is configured though, you might not be able to see the console window when it runs.

Comment: You can't use SC to set up a batch file as a service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152216/discussion-between-andyb-and-miki-jay).

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is resolved by now, but in case it helps anyone,  what saved the day for me was checking again my input in the arguments field in nssm. I had an extra "-" which created the error. To edit my service, I went via  `nssm edit <servicename>`

Answer (score 0):

I would also add on the fix that worked for me. I added "" (quotes) in the argument path and that solved the issue for me.